# change the values in same column to zero and one

Tags: r

i want to replace all values greater than 0 to 0 and all the values equal to 0 to 1. i am able to convert one by one but what is the best and easiest way in single line of code ..?

i have tried the below approach but its changing everything to 0 or everything to 1

```
df <- data.frame(cc=c(1,NA,3,NA,4,NA,23,17,NA,0),
                 bb=c(0,NA,12,NA,2,0,NA,12,14,0),
                 dd=c(12,0,0,NA,3,0,NA,23,7,9))


df1 <- df %>% mutate(across(c(cc, bb,dd), ~replace(., .>0, 0)),across(c(cc, bb,dd), ~replace(., .=0, 1)))
```

the overall objective is to replace values greater than 0 to 0 and values equals to 0 to 1

the output should look like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is:

```
ifelse(!df, 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
      cc bb dd
 [1,]  0  1  0
 [2,] NA NA  1
 [3,]  0  0  1
 [4,] NA NA NA
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,] NA  1  1
 [7,]  0 NA NA
 [8,]  0  0  0
 [9,] NA  0  0
[10,]  1  1  0
```

You can also just use `!df`, if you are okay with using `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, they're different to `1`s and `0`s, but behave the same way in practice.

Comment: but i have more other columns in my database what should be the approach

Comment: ah and you are only wanting to do it to a few columns?

Comment: yes for few columns only , i want to do both things in one line , just wanted to check the the different approaches

Comment: df |> mutate(across(cc:dd, ~ ifelse(!.x, 1, 0))) try that!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below code.

```
+!df
      cc bb dd
 [1,]  0  1  0
 [2,] NA NA  1
 [3,]  0  0  1
 [4,] NA NA NA
 [5,]  0  0  0
 [6,] NA  1  1
 [7,]  0 NA NA
 [8,]  0  0  0
 [9,] NA  0  0
[10,]  1  1  0
```

To apply to specific columns, one can do this.

```
f <- \(x) +!(x)
df %>%
  mutate(across(1:3, f))
```

Comment: This is so cool! What is this actually doing?

Comment: The `!` converts numeric values equal to 0 as TRUE and all others as FALSE (as you nicely demonstrated in your answer). The `+` is a workaround way of converting the logical values to numeric.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give a more detailed explanation as that's about as far as my understanding of that goes :).

Comment: Thanks for that. Small note- it appears that OP wants it to only happen for a few columns-see the comments under my answer

Comment: yes this is changing the whole columns but i want for few columns

Comment: Mark's comment below his answer using `mutate` and `across` should work for specific columns.